# How to determin which admin screen/sub screen I'm currently viewing

Tags: admin-menu

**Edit:** The Q narrowed down to the following:

> "How would I retrieve the screen IDs of all admin UI screens at one time?"

---

**Edit:** I added a bunch of more plugin globals.

---

**Q** is the following: Check **which AdminUI submenu page/screen you're viewing** and check this **against some global var or some internal function**.

```
// This helps you inspecting the data - just drop it in some functions.php file of a theme
function wpse_inspect_admin_screen_data()
{
    echo '<pre>';
        echo '<h3>global <code>$menu</code></h3>';
        print_r( $GLOBALS['menu'] );
        echo '<hr />';

        echo '<h3>global <code>$submenu</code></h3>';
        print_r( $GLOBALS['submenu'] );
        echo '<hr />';

        echo '<h3>global <code>$self</code></h3>';
        print_r( $GLOBALS['self'] );
        echo '<hr />';

        echo '<h3>global <code>$parent_file</code></h3>';
        print_r( $GLOBALS['parent_file'] );
        echo '<hr />';

        echo '<h3>global <code>$submenu_file</code></h3>';
        print_r( $GLOBALS['submenu_file'] );
        echo '<hr />';

        echo '<h3>global <code>$plugin_page</code></h3>';
        print_r( $GLOBALS['plugin_page'] );
        echo '<hr />';

        echo '<h3>global <code>$admin_page_hooks</code></h3>';
        print_r( $GLOBALS['admin_page_hooks'] );
        echo '<hr />';

        echo '<h3>global <code>$_parent_pages</code></h3>';
        print_r( $GLOBALS['_parent_pages'] );
        echo '<hr />';

        echo '<h3>global <code>$_registered_pages</code></h3>';
        print_r( $GLOBALS['_registered_pages'] );
        echo '<hr />';

        echo '<h3>global <code>$title</code></h3>';
        print_r( $GLOBALS['title'] );
        echo '<hr />';

        echo '<h3>global <code>$_wp_real_parent_file</code></h3>';
        print_r( $GLOBALS['_wp_real_parent_file'] );
        echo '<hr />';

        echo '<h3>global <code>$_wp_menu_nopriv</code></h3>';
        print_r( $GLOBALS['_wp_menu_nopriv'] );
        echo '<hr />';

        echo '<h3>global <code>$_wp_submenu_nopriv</code></h3>';
        print_r( $GLOBALS['_wp_submenu_nopriv'] );
        echo '<hr />';

        // built by set_current_screen() in /core_root/wp-admin/includes/template.php line 2085 (wp 3.2.x)
        echo '<h3>global <code>$current_screen</code></h3>';
        print_r( $GLOBALS['current_screen'] );
    echo '<pre>';
}
add_action( 'shutdown', 'wpse_inspect_admin_screen_data', 9999 );
```

I already have an Array containing the slug and Label from both the parent and sub menu item. Here you can see an exemplary part of the array I built from `global $menu, $submenu;` and that I need to check against:

```
Array
(
    [Appearance] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Themes
                    [slug] => themes.php
                    [parent_label] => Appearance
                    [parent_file] => themes.php
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Widgets
                    [slug] => widgets.php
                    [parent_label] => Appearance
                    [parent_file] => themes.php
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Editor
                    [slug] => theme-editor.php
                    [parent_label] => Appearance
                    [parent_file] => themes.php
                )
        )
    [Pages] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [label] => All Pages
                    [slug] => edit.php?post_type=page
                    [parent_label] => Pages
                    [parent_file] => edit.php?post_type=page
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Add New
                    [slug] => post-new.php?post_type=page
                    [parent_label] => Pages
                    [parent_file] => edit.php?post_type=page
                )
        )
)
```

---

**Note:** The Q is *not* the loop. Only what *exactly* I can use to check which menu item *and* subitem I'm currently watching.

Comment: I was writing an admin menu some time ago and had to work out how pages were determined myself. I'm not sure if this code is from an older version, it's from a backup, and i'm not sure if i have more recent code somewhere, but here's [a pastebin of some code i played around with](http://pastebin.com/gkrVQJsh)(pretty sure i have a more recent copy somewhere but this is all i could find by quickly looking, so hope it's helpful).

Comment: There's a missing JS file to go with that code but i don't seem to have a backup of it. I know i have a more recent copy uploaded on a testing website(though how much it differs i don't know), so i can always go grab that if necessary, just pointing out that the code posted is incomplete, figured you might appreciate taking a look at it all the same.

Comment: Oh, lol, there may also be some test stuff in there, along with some data i collected and commented into the end of the file(i didn't check what i was pasting before i did it).. so feel free to discard anything not relevant..

Comment: @t31os Hey, thanks for your comments (should be an answer - I'd appreciate to up vote that effort). Basically your menu loop (using the menu/submenu, skipping the separators) is pretty much the same. If you have an e-mail address, I'd mail to you. So far my biggest problem is the following Q: "_How would I retrieve the screen IDs of all admin UI screens at one time?_". Solving this would allow me to check against the array of screen IDs and identify the current page. Hopefully this also allows a ticket for a better and easier admin menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we now have `get_current_screen()`, which returns a nice object, it's become fairly easy to just use that.

Answer (score 2):

Since admin menu itself knows how to display where you are at, it is reasonable to look at code responsible for that logic.

Menu output is generated by [`_wp_menu_output()` in `menu-header.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.2/wp-admin/menu-header.php#L36). It makes use of number of global variables, namely:

```
global $self, $parent_file, $submenu_file, $plugin_page, $pagenow, $typenow;
```

The actual logic is quite extensive and naturally differs for native and plugin pages. Look for assignments of `'current'` to CSS classes and around.